# Transport rule disclaimer in new emails before sending

Tags: email, exchange-2010, rules

I have created a transport rule in exchange 2010 so attach disclaimers to emails.  Is it possible to make this disclaimers visible in the newly created email before it is sent?

Comment: Disclaimers on emails are extremely silly in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Transport rules only apply as the email goes through Exchange. It doesn't apply before. If you want something to show in the email then you will need something client side.

Most third party disclaimer/signature management tools work in the same way - applying the text after the email has been sent.